# Xcode Update SDK to 10.9

Tags: macos, install, xcode

I ran the update for Mavericks as well as the Xcode 5.1 update (build 5B130a) and I can't find a way to update my OS X SDK from 10.8 to 10.9 (The only updates that show up are iOS SDK 6.1 and the docsets).

I was looking forward to using Sprite Kit on my Macbook Pro (10.9.2), but the SDK just does not show up. SpriteKit is definitely on my system, though, because `/System/Library/Frameworks/SpriteKit.framework/` exists. When I add the SpriteKit framework directly from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SpriteKit.framework` it can't find it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally forgot to rename Xcode 4.0 and left it as Xcode.app in `/Applications/Xcode Older Versions/` which is what I used to store Xcode 4 in case the old Xcode 5 developer previews had any issues. So that bundle was replaced, not 5.0.

The weird thing is that even when I was sure I had it 5.1 open SpriteKit Game didn't show up as an option. Rebooting fixed that.

Oops.